# How to retain comment text with tag in XSL?

Tags: html, xslt

HTML:

```
<p>The effect of GCs on brown adipose growth and function is unknown and may contribute to the negative energy balance observed clinically.</p>
<!--<jid>JOE</jid><aid>140538</aid>-->
<p>Clinical cases of glucocorticoid (GC) excess are characterized by increased fat mass and obesity through the accumulation of white adipocytes.</p>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<para>The effect of GCs on brown adipose growth and function is unknown and may contribute to the negative energy balance observed clinically.</para>
&lt;jid&gt;JOE&lt;/jid&gt;&lt;aid&gt;140538&lt;/aid&gt;
<para>Clinical cases of glucocorticoid (GC) excess are characterized by increased fat mass and obesity through the accumulation of white adipocytes.</para>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="comment()">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
<para>The effect of GCs on brown adipose growth and function is unknown and may contribute to the negative energy balance observed clinically.</para>
<jid>JOE</jid><aid>140538</aid>
<para>Clinical cases of glucocorticoid (GC) excess are characterized by increased fat mass and obesity through the accumulation of white adipocytes.</para>
```

The tag is going to change as entity. But, I want to keep the comment of the same in the output also. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `disable-output-escaping`.

```
<xsl:template match="comment()">
  <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If using 'xsl:copy-of' means comment also came. For eg: <!--<jid>JOE</jid><aid>140538</aid>-->

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. It seems you want to output the content of the comment as XML. To do so, use `disable-output-escaping`. See my updated answer above.